# raspberry pi2(jessie) へのmultipathTCPのインストール方法

Tags: raspberry-pi

raspberry pi2(jessie) にmultipathTCPをインストール方法をどなたか教えてください。

以下のmultipath-tcp.orgのサイトで確認してみましたがインストール方法の情報は無く「Debian Jessie for the newest release:」の方法で試してみましたが成功しませんでした。
https://multipath-tcp.org/pmwiki.php/Users/AptRepository

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

Raspberry Pi2のアーキテクチャ(ARMv7)はサポートされていないようです。動かない理由はないと思うので、ソースを取ってきて、コンパイルしましょう。Raspberry Pi2でコンパイルすると日が暮れるので母艦でクロスコンパイルすると良いでしょう。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]